# How to set up BIOS-like password on Android device?

Tags: factory-reset, boot, bootloader, bootloader-lock

Setting a screen lock password or SIM pin or both is fine for securing some aspects of your mobile device. But what if, as a nasty joke, someone manages to grab a hold of your device and hits the magic power-home-volume key combination and proceeds to factory reset your device thus deleting your folder configuration, a record of what unpaid apps you had downloaded, and what is more, data stored on your phone!

So, is there a way to set up a password so that it must be entered when such magic key combination is issued (so that you can't factory reset your device without entering such a "BIOS" password?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Would be tricky if you forget that password. As you'd no longer be able to reset the device (or reflash it), you could "throw it away" then. If you're afraid of your data being deleted, a backup is the better approach – and against data theft, some anti-theft solution.

Comment: I'd never forget that damn password @Izzy. There must be a solution. Backups are good, but I want to be able to set a BIOS password. I don't want anyone areound me to reset my device.

Comment: I *knew* I answered that question already one day :) Thanks for digging that up, @Arch!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only thing similar to this that I can think of is device encryption, it's built in to the settings panel. Every time you power on your phone, you are required to enter a pass-code, that you created. If you forget it, it will be more difficult to get back into your phone

**How To**

1. Go to settings
2. Click Security
3. Under the Encryption group, hit Encrypt device (or phone on older devices)
4. Now it will guide you through the next steps.

Comment: Thanks. How do I enable this on my android device?

Comment: Actually, there is a way to get back in a device with a forgotten encryption password. You just have to wipe the device from its recovery menu, or plug it into a computer and use appropriate software if there is no such menu.

Comment: @Arielle Thanks for the clarification, I updated my answer in response.

Comment: I wonder why this answer is approved! Device Encryption will not prevent factory reset or will it ?

Comment: Device encryption prevents unauthorised access to data. It does not prevent unauthorized factory reset from recovery menu. If it does, please do explain.